# Sprite not moving with cusor in three.js r71

Tags: javascript, three.js

When I move the cursor, the sprite is visible but not properly moving along with the cursor point. It is moving in opposite direction. Please help.

```
sprite1.position.set( event.clientX *(-.4) , event.clientY *(.4) , 1 );
mouse.x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;
```

Comment: Could you please give some more details? Code snippets?

Comment: sprite1.position.set( event.clientX *(-.4) , event.clientY *(.4) , 1 );

mouse.x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
 mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;

Answer (score 0):

Whenever something is "moving in opposite direction" in the 3d world, it is useful negating whatever that is:

```
mouse.x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ); 
mouse.y = ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ); 

//mouse is now somewhere between 0..1 for both x and y

//if you want this to go in the opposite direction
mouse.x = 1 - mouse.x;
mouse.y = 1 - mouse.y;


//if it goes from -1 to 1 you scale it:
mouse.x = mouse.x * 2 - 1; //first it goes from 0..2 then -1...1


//reversing this is
mouse.x = -mouse.x;
```

this on the other hand:

```
sprite1.position.set( event.clientX *(-.4) , event.clientY *(.4)
```

will be hard to achieve. It seems you are projecting your screen coordinates in pixels, to some world units (otherwise i'm not sure you'd get them to show up). If you are working only in the positive range, flipping -4 to 4 will move it offscreen. You'd need to do add an offset, so subtract 8 for example.